# match and replace cell values from 1 sheet to another

Tags: excel

i have two excel sheets i.e. sheet1 sheet2 and both has more then 10000 rows, sheet1 F has numeric values.If last three digit of these values match from sheet2 A, replace the complete value of that cell from the sheet2 D data.

Answer (score 1):

To actually replace cell values would require a VBA macro. Alternatively, you could create a new column and use a lookup formula to compare the last three digits and populate with either the original value from column F or a replacement value from Sheet 2. This would then become your new column F.
To get the last three digits you can use

```
    =right($F1, 3)
```

which will give you the last three characters from F1.
Use an IF statement to compare the two values

```
    =IF(right($F1, 3)=Sheet2!$A1, Sheet2!$D1, $F1)
```

This compares the last three digits of F1 with Sheet2 A1 and returns Sheet2 D1 if they match or the original F1 if they don't.

I am assuming that you are matching row for row, as three digits would repeat over a 10000 row range.